Solving the Poisson equation $-\Delta u=f$ on a domain $G$
Let $G$ be a domain and $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We want to solve
$$-\Delta u =f \text{ in } G$$
without any boundary condition. Can we just take $\Delta^{-1}$ the inverse Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which defines a solution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and say that the solution can be written on $G$ via the singular integral $\Delta^{-1}f$,
$$u(x)=(\Delta^{-1}f)(x) \text{ for all } x\in G?$$

Yes, you are completely right. However, I think there is an issue that $f \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and not $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If the latter was the case, you could look up all the details in Evans textbook.
Instead, you can show that for $f \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$
u(x)= \frac{1}{\alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}dy
$$
is a weak/distributional solution to
$$
\Delta u=f
$$
and by elliptic regularity theory, it must also be a classical solution. So your singular integral argument will still work, but I don't know if there is a more straightforward way to prove that the formula still holds for $f \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
